# JBox2D 2.1.2 Expection (new world creation)

Tags: jbox2d

I try to create an application for mobile phone LG GT-540 (Android 2.1).
The application does not work if I initialize the new world
...
world = new World(gravity, doSleep);

Will be grateful for any ideas how to overcome this problem...

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem as this exception

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.bind(LoggerFactory.java:121)
    at org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.performInitialization(LoggerFactory.java:111)
```

it told I don't include the slf4j dependency，but jbox2d-library-2.1.2.jar has already include slfj4, so you could change the "slf4j" package inside the jbox2d.jar to the most recent version,it would fix this error.

and this jbox2d issue refers [here](http://code.google.com/p/jbox2d/issues/detail?id=26#c11), you could find the most recent version of slf4j in that page.

Comment: Please insert the relevant parts of this link to your answer (among others, to prevent link rot)